# asp-page tag in dropdown menu razaor page

Tags: drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, razor-pages

i have drop down menu with  tags :

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown dark-bg-like-top">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       My Blog
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
       <a class="dropdown-item" asp-page="/Blogs/123" >First Blog</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

it's working well in the home page (index), when i click the drop down it work well and when i click the blog link it work(/Blogs/123), but when i click it from any other page rather than the home page the link contain the current page link , not the blog link, example : from page /Pages/xyz then the dropdown link become /Pages/xyz not /Blogs/123

what is the wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a . before the link to indicate your link is from the web root and not relative to the current location e.g. `"./Blogs/123"`